# Visual Studio 2019 View in Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to Visual Studio and I am working on a school project (.net framework) using a pc with Windows 10. I would like to use my Mac instead, but there are features that I can't find on the mac version, one of them being the "view on browser option." Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac is not a 1:1 replica of VS for Windows.  The feature you are interested in may not exist on the mac side.  If you include a screenshot of the feature, or a description of where it lives in VS that would be helpful.

Comment: setup a local web server on mac, that can run asp.net, and there you go, you can browser it there

Comment: It definitely is not a replica. I gave up on trying to use it on a mac and using the pc version instead. Thank you for your help.